# Request failed for fedex API in google sheets app scripts

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to integrate fedex tracking into google sheets by using fedex api. I have gotten to this far but am now receiving error code 400 from fedex.

I am receiving an error code from fedex (return code 400)

```
Exception: Request failed for https://apis.fedex.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: {"transactionId": "bdc46ab9-8aa0-4854-baa7-5526739c0fb9","errors":[{"code":"BAD.REQUEST.ERROR","message":"The given JWT is invalid. Please modify y... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) trackPackage
```

```
@ Code.gs:10
```

Sorry I am not a developer so if there are any errors or mistakes please let me know

The code I was running was:

```
function trackPackage(trackingNumber) {

  // Get the FedEx API key and secret from the Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var apiKey = sheet.getRange('A2').getValue();
  var apiSecret = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();

  // Create a new request
  var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://apis.fedex.com/track/v1/trackingnumbers', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      tracking_numbers: [trackingNumber]
    }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-locale': 'en_US',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "l736f80=====14243==ca0dda" + ':' + "68938dba=====c9c6==d55ca"
    }
  });

  // Handle the response
  request.onResponse(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      // The request was successful, so parse the JSON response
      var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

      // Loop through the tracking results and add them to the Google Sheet
      for (var i = 0; i < responseData.tracking_results.length; i++) {
        var result = responseData.tracking_results[i];

        // Add the tracking number to the Google Sheet
        sheet.getRange('A' + (i + 1)).setValue(result.tracking_number);

        // Add the status to the Google Sheet
        sheet.getRange('B' + (i + 1)).setValue(result.status);

        // Add the location to the Google Sheet
        sheet.getRange('C' + (i + 1)).setValue(result.location);

        // Add the date and time to the Google Sheet
        sheet.getRange('D' + (i + 1)).setValue(result.date_time);
      }
    } else {
      // The request failed, so display an error message
      alert('Error: ' + response.status);
    }
  });
}
```

I have tried to rerun and the script and but cannot identify what error code 400 means

Comment: Unfortunately, UrlFetchApp has no property of `body`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) I thought that when your access token is valid, the reason for your current issue of `BAD.REQUEST.ERROR` might be due to this. In this case, how about modifying `body: JSON.stringify({tracking_numbers: [trackingNumber]}),` to `payload: JSON.stringify({tracking_numbers: [trackingNumber]}),`?

Comment: Hey Tanaike, I replace body to payload but still resulted in the same error code

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful.

Comment: You assign values to `apiKey` and `apiSecret` but neither variable is used in your script. Is that significant?

Comment: The apiKey and apisecret is used in the line after the word bearer